# How to check PostgreSql is installed or not in windows machine using C#.net?

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, installation

I have a WPF application with PostgreSQL, I need to check PostgreSQL is installed in the local machine.

```
const string PostgresSQLKeyName = "SOFTWARE\\PostgreSQL\\Installations\\postgresql-x64-9.4";
const string NetRegKeyValue = "DllFullPath";

private static bool GetRegistryValue<T>(RegistryHive hive, string key, string value, RegistryValueKind kind, out T data)
{
    bool success = false;
    data = default(T);

    using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(hive, String.Empty)) {
        if (baseKey != null) {
            using (RegistryKey registryKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(key, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree)) {
                if (registryKey != null) {
                    try {
                        // If the key was opened, try to retrieve the value.
                        RegistryValueKind kindFound = registryKey.GetValueKind(value);
                        if (kindFound == kind) {
                            object regValue = registryKey.GetValue(value, null);
                            if (regValue != null) {
                                data = (T)Convert.ChangeType(regValue, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                success = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        //Logger.Write(ex, "GetRegistryValue-Detection.cs", "GetRegistryValue");
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

But I am always getting the result false (= not installed) even if I installed it. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you call this method? Which hive?

Comment: What if another versions of PostgreSQL is installed ?

Comment: @ Vivek , postgresql-x64-9.4 ,is already installed in my machine

Comment: try [this](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/programmatically-determine-if-windows.html) way, its a good one

Answer (score 1):

Check Registry Entry using C#

```
var postgres = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\pgadmin");
if(postgres != null)
{
    //postgreSQL is installed on your machine
}
```